# systemd target multi-user.target failed, but how to know why?

Tags: systemd

How can I diagnose the causes of this inactive state ?

```
# systemctl --type=target --no-pager
UNIT                   LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB    JOB   DESCRIPTION
basic.target           loaded active   active       Basic System
cryptsetup.target      loaded active   active       Local Encrypted Volumes
getty.target           loaded active   active       Login Prompts
local-fs-pre.target    loaded active   active       Local File Systems (Pre)
local-fs.target        loaded active   active       Local File Systems
multi-user.target      loaded inactive dead   start Multi-User System
network-online.target  loaded active   active       Network is Online
network.target         loaded active   active       Network
nss-user-lookup.target loaded active   active       User and Group Name Lookups
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn't failed *yet* – the "JOB" column indicates that there is still a 'start' job pending. Check what other units are waiting for startup:

```
systemctl list-jobs
```

Comment: fixed in the meantime    
via a 'systemctl  list-dependencies multi-user.target' and searching for red application-services : an applicative daemon failed at boot time, with target requiredBy in its service    
could have your command help ? here the failed job is not pending